# Spring Roo generating errors in ActiveRecord.aj for EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I am using Roo 1.3.2. I have an abstract class and a concrete implementation as follows:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord(inheritanceType="TABLE_PER_CLASS")    
public abstract class Task {
        @Size(min = 2)
        private String name;
        public abstract void execute(Object... parameters);
}

@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class ImportLoadPlanTask extends Task {
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String svnFile;

    @Override
    public void execute(Object... parameters){
        ....
    }
}
```

However the ActiveRecord.aj file generated produces the following code

```
public static final EntityManager Task.entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new Task() {
            public void execute(java.lang.Object parameters) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        }.entityManager;
        if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
        return em;
    }
```

And the error message from the IDE is :

```
The type new Task(){} must implement the inherited abstract Task.execute(Object ...)
```

If I remove the abstract keyword from the Task class, the error disappears as Roo does not attempt to generate the code listed above.

How can I get this to work? Is this a Roo bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug detecting the type of `parameters` parameter. Please, can you report it on [Spring Roo Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO)?

To solve it just use *push-in*:

```
public abstract class Task {
    @Size(min = 2)
    private String name;
    public abstract void execute(Object... parameters);

    // Push-in entityManager method from .aj file
    public static final EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManager em = new Task() {
            public void execute(Object... parameters) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        }.entityManager;
       if (em == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Entity manager has not been injected (is the Spring Aspects JAR configured as an AJC/AJDT aspects library?)");
       return em;
    }
}
```

That's is one of the main points of Spring Roo: Always you can do it your way!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response and I will try out your suggestion. I have logged a bug. Out of interest you can find it here [ROO-3688](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3688?jql=project%20%3D%20ROO)